# What is time complexity of random indexing characters access in UTF-8 encoded string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, utf-8, time-complexity

What is time complexity of random indexing characters access  in UTF-8 encoded string in Ruby?

When i run this code in command line interpreter:

```
s = "абв"
puts s.encoding.name
print s.bytes
puts
puts s.length
puts s[1]
```

it outputs:

```
UTF-8
[208, 176, 208, 177, 208, 178]
3
б
```

so i guess, when i try to get ith character from string, i have O(n) operations, where n is length of the string. Is it correct? I couldn't find some information about this in official documentation. In my opinion it's very important.

Comment: Ruby could have a data structure that maps characters to indices.

Answer (score 3):

UTF-8 does not support random indexing of characters. A character can be encoded as anything from one to four octets. Therefore, to find the `i`th character, you have to read all octets from the beginning of the string until you arrive at the `i`th character. That means, to find the `i`th character you have to read anywhere between `i` and `4*i` octets.

Note that, of course, it doesn't stop here. For example, my name can be written in two ways: `J` + `ö` + `r` + `g`, which is four characters that are encoded as five octets in UTF-8. Or, it can be written as `J` + `o` + **combining character diaeresis** + `r` + `g`, which is *five* characters encoded as six octets.

So, without knowing whether the string is normalized or not and which normalization form it is using, if any, you don't even know whether `r` is the third or fourth character of my name.

If you index into the string to get the third character, you might get the  **combining character diaeresis** which doesn't even make sense on its own, because it needs to be combined with a previous character to form a glyph. However, you also cannot assume that the previous character is "useful" because combining characters can be "stacked", so the previous character could again be a combining character.

Comment: Yes, UTF-8 doesn't but Ruby does. I mean in Ruby s[i] is `i`th character of string (and it works even if i mix one-byte and multi-byte characters) but not a `i`th byte. So it means compiler (interpreter) generates code which pass through characters to get `i`th of it, doesn't it?

Comment: So time complexity of subscript operator is O(n). In other languase it has O(1) time complexity, that's why i think authors should add this information in description.

Comment: "In other languase it has O(1) time complexity" – That is not possible. UTF-8 does not support random access. That is a limitation of UTF-8, not of the language. In fact, it is a limitation of *every* variable-width transfer encoding. *No* language can provide random character access in UTF-8 in better than O(n), unless they have a very complicated string type, where they keep a separate list of character indices. (But building this list is also O(n) time and the list has O(n) space.)

Comment: It's possible. Because UTF-8 encoded string literals are transformed into UTF-16 to store internally. And random access will work correct in most cases except surrogate pairs. The case of surrogate pairs is not processed specially. And access is O(1) in common case. Ruby is only language where UTF-8 doesn't converted into UTF-16 that i know. It's very poor solution, because O(n) character access is not obvious.

Comment: I know how UTF-8 encoding works. I wrote UTF-8 conversion algorithm  to UTF-16 by myself. Maybe it's about my bad English. But the question is not about encoding but about Ruby. Why Ruby allows random access to character but not specificates that operation is slow?

Comment: I can give a lot of examples where UTF-8 is converted into UTF-16: Java, C#, JavaScript, Python, C++ Qt QStrings and more others.

Comment: "So time complexity of subscript operator is O(n). In other languase it has O(1) time complexity, that's why i think authors should add this information in description. " 

I meant exactly time complexity of subscription operation, not how strings are stored.

Comment: "Why Ruby allows random access to character but not specificates that operation is slow?" – If you choose to store your strings in an encoding that does not support random access to characters in O(1) when you need random access to characters to be O(1), then there really is nothing that Ruby can do about that. Ruby supports plenty of encodings where random access to characters *is* O(1), such as ASCII, ISO 8859-1, ISO 8859-2, ISO 8859-3, ISO 8859-4, ISO 8859-5, ISO 8859-6, ISO 8859-7, ISO 8859-8, ISO 8859-9, ISO 8859-10, ISO 8859-11, ISO 8859-12, ISO 8859-13, ISO 8859-14, ISO 8859-15, …

Comment: … ISO 8859-16, Windows-1250, Windows-1251, Windows-1252, Windows-1253, Windows-1254, Windows-1257, IBM437, IBM737, IBM775, CP850, IBM852, CP852, IBM855, CP855, IBM857, IBM860, IBM861, IBM862, IBM863, IBM864, IBM865, IBM866, IBM869, Windows-1258, Mac Roman, Mac Cent+Euro, , UTF-32LE, UTF-32BE, and many, many, many more. In all of those, random access to characters is O(1). So, if you choose an encoding where character access is not O(1) when you actually need character access in O(1), there is nothing that Ruby can do about it. You still have to know what you are doing, even in Ruby.

Comment: It should be explicitly pointed. Like in Swift, where operation like s[i] is not allowed at all. You just can get a "pointer" to position in string and in the documentation it's noted as O(n) operation.

Why should i know that Ruby doesn't convert string to UTF-16 internally just like Java or C#? And in that case s[i] has O(1).

I do not know why Ruby outputs s.encoding.name as UTF-8 in that case, may be as string source encoding. But in my opinion it's very real scenario.

Comment: Ok. I want to get summary. Here is pseudo-code:

`s = "just a string literal"
for i = 1 to s.length do
  print s[i]
end`

Will it have O(n^2) time complexity (where n is s.length) in Ruby in case of UTF-8 encoded source?

Comment: That depends on what the encoding of `s` is. If the encoding of `s` has random access to characters in O(1), then random access to characters in `s` is O(1). If the encoding of `s` has random access to characters in O(n), then random access to characters in `s` is O(n). If the encoding of `s` has random access to characters in O(log n^π), then random access to characters in `s` is O(log n^π). You have to choose the encoding that matches your use case.

Comment: Note that the Ruby Language Specification does not make *any* guarantees about runtime *at all*, for *any* method. So, technically speaking, the answer to your question is that the runtime could be anywhere from O(1) (because the input is known in advance and could be optimized at compile time) to O(n^9999999999) (because the Ruby Language Specification makes no guarantees about runtimes of methods). Most likely, it will either be O(n) or O(n^2), depending on the encoding and the optimizations of the particular implementation. (E.g. I can imagine an implementation tagging UTF-8 strings that …

Comment: … only contain ASCII characters with a special flag that tells the method that it can safely index by computing the offset in memory, or I can imagine an implementation keeping a separate lookup table of character start indices.) But none of that is in any way guaranteed and/or required by the language specification.